# jQuery ajax cache disabling not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, caching

I'm developing a Firefox extension that uses an ajax-request to retrieve information. This is the code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/Service?wsdl" + new Date().getTime(),
        beforeSend: function(request) { request.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "Group"); },         
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",   
        dataType: "xml",
        data: req,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: function (data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest) {
        out = $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML);
        }
    });
```

I still get the same result, when the data that is sent to the server is changed. I tried to avoid that by adding "new Date().getTime()" to the URL and "cache: false". This doesn't seem to work. After restarting the browser, I get the correct results.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?
Is there some kind of session-handling, so the server still gives back the old response?

Edit: I did a lot of testing and debugging and I think I found the problem: there is a cookie saved with every ajax-request that contains a session-id, so every time I do the request again, the server sends data of the session with the session-id in the cookie. Really bad behavior, I didn't know that cookies could be created through an ajax-request.
So everything I have to do to fix the problem is a function that deletes this cookie every time my parameters are changed. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: did you try any of those suggestions ??

Comment: Yeah, i tried both suggestions now (by Dr. Molle and by gov), but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: is it , are you doing any caching on server side ???

Comment: I don't have any influence on what is done on server side, but I already checked that with a SOAP client and the replies were correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

try toger with Math.random() to be on safer side

Date().getTime() together with Math.random()

```
http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/Service?wsdl" + new Date().getTime() + Math.random()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an ampersand before the timestamp:

```
http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/Service?wsdl&" + new Date().getTime()
```

I guess the wsdl-parameter makes sense there inside the url, without the ampersand you destroy the parameter.